# Transforming XML using XSLT Exception: "System.OutOfMemoryException at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString() "

Tags: xml, xslt, out-of-memory, stringbuilder, stringwriter

Hi I am facing the serious issue when transforming the **XML** using **XSLT**:

```
System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform XSLTR = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform();
XSLTR.Transform(XPathNavigator input, XsltArgumentList args, TextWriter output);
```

I inputted XML which has 20.000 rows. It throws the following error:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()   at System.IO.StringWriter.ToString()

Can anyone give some suggestions for solving this issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Obviously your transformation is taking up too much memory. Considering reducing the complexity of the XSLT or batching the transformation into chunks. Without seeing the code - which I doubt we want to when it's a 20 000 row document - we can't really help you specifically. =)

Comment: @J.Steen thanks for your reply. The XML is quite complex and my requirement to transform the 1 Lakh rows using XSLT. so i made chunks of 20000 rows.I tried with the 12500 rows it worked fine. Is there anyway to provide the resources(more RAM kind) for string.

Comment: Why are you transforming to a StringWriter, do you really need the transformation result in memory as a string? If you transform to a file with a method like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms163431 then you don't need that much memory. And since .NET 2.0 the preferred XSLT processor is `XslCompiledTransform`, `XslTransform` is obsolete. Whether that helps reducing the memory consumption is another issue however.

Comment: You could try a different XSLT processor (Saxon or XmlPrime) to see if it does any better. It's just possible that one of the processors has an optimization that makes a difference. But more likely, there's some inefficiency in your XSLT code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @vineet Maybe your XML files are too large to fit into the RAM. How big are those files? It's also possible your XSLT is inefficient. Without seeing the XML and XSLT it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I need not the transformation as a string in memory but all methods requires the string writer as a param so i used this method. I have changed the XslTransform to XslCompiledTransform as u suggested. XslCompiledTransformTransform Method (String, String) requires the uri as parameter but i have loaded the xml in xmldocument . Is there any other method that i can use.

Comment: @Tomalak I am able to attach the xml and xsl files here as i haven't seen any option to attach files.

Comment: vineet, if you have an `XmlDocument` as the input and you want to transform to a file then it suffices to use `XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform(); proc.Load("sheet.xsl"); using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("result.xml")) { proc.Transform(xmlDocumentInstance, null, fs); }`, there certainly is no need to store the transformation result as a string in memory.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Instead of writing the file by filestream, output xml   can be saved in xmldocument ??.So that i can use it for further processing instead of writing the file and reading back the xml file.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, if the memory suffices, use `XmlDocument resultDoc = new XmlDocument(); using (XmlWriter xw = resultDocument.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()) { proc.Transform(xmlInputDocumentInstance, null, xw); xw.Close(); }`, then you can use the `resultDocument`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks a ton. this seems to work for me.I will test for some time.

Comment: I will put the suggestions made in the comment in an answer so that you can mark the problem as solved.

Comment: XslTransform is *obsolete* and it is recommended to use XslCompiledTransform instead.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Why don't you tone it down a bit (and I don't mean just here, I mean *all* of your comments)?  While direct (which is fine), telling someone to RTFM is rude, and we don't do rude here.  *Tone it down*.  Consider this an official warning.

Comment: @casperOne♦: You removed my suggestion to the OP to read the appropriate documentation -- this was the best advice someone could give him. While I cannot give you an "official warning", please, kindly consider this as a strong, unofficial warning that in this case you are not doing good work by deleting useful suggestions. Now, that I have this experience with you, I would never vote for you as moderator -- yes, I know that moderators aren't re-elected, which is a pity.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I edited the rudeness out of it.  If you want to take another shot at it, I can delete your comment and you can try again.  As for your "unofficial warning", you can always go to [Meta] if you have an issue with specific moderation issues.  As for not voting for me as moderator, etc. that's an example of the rudeness I am speaking of.  Again, please refrain from that kind of response on Stack Overflow or further moderation actions may be taken against you.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev And to be clear, we don't do "Google it" or "RTFM" here, regardless of whether or not *you* think it's the best answer.  If that's *truly* the case, then there is more than likely an issue with the question itself, and you should vote to close/delete/flag for moderator attention as appropriate (which you've done here).  Commenting beyond that is not necessary.

Comment: casperOne♦: Your last comment shows neglect for user feedback on the quality of your work. I think *this* is really rude.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Actually, I pointed you to [Meta] which is *exactly* the place to provide user feedback on all things SO, moderation included.  That said, while standards of rudeness are subjective, I've actually assisted you in providing feedback in the proper place in the system.

Comment: @MartinHonnen When i tried to write a big transformed xml data to excel using openxml..its given me a big exception..this is my code::public void AddPartXml(OpenXmlPart part, string xml)
       
{
            using (Stream stream = part.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(xml);
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
Can u guide me how i can write the xml in chunk to excel.

Comment: vineet, that is a completely different problem so you will have to post a new question with all details shown.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i have asked new question u can reach on this by this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675041/exporting-huge-xml-to-excel-using-openxml

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid storing the transformation result in a string, if you want a file as the transformation result then there is an overload of the `Transform` method allowing you to write to a `FileStream`:

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform(); 

proc.Load("sheet.xsl"); 

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("result.xml")) 
{ 
  proc.Transform(xmlDocumentInstance, null, fs);
}
```

If you want an `XmlDocument` as the result, you can achieve that as follows:

```
XmlDocument resultDoc = new XmlDocument();

using (XmlWriter xw = resultDocument.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()) 
{ 
  proc.Transform(xmlInputDocumentInstance, null, xw); 
  xw.Close();
}
```