# Exporting huge xml to excel using Openxml

Tags: c#, xml, stream, openxml, export-to-excel

I tried to write a big transformed xml data to excel using openxml sdk 2.0..its given me a big exception.i think the Open xml  is not supportive to write the bulk data to excel..i was able to write 50000 rows. this is my code::

```
 public void AddPartXml(OpenXmlPart part, string xml)
     { 
        using (Stream stream = part.GetStream())
        {
          byte[] buffer = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(xml);
          stream.Write(buffer, 0,buffer.Length);
          stream.Dispose();
        } 
    }
```

Is there any possibility that we can write data to exce in chunk instead of writing in one shot.

Comment: Please format your code so it's easy to read.

Comment: What was the "big exception" you got?

Comment: Note that all versions of excel have a maximum number of rows they can display. Generally, this is 65535 (Int16). Excel will ignore any further records. This limit is per-sheet not per-workbook so you could break the data up if needs be

Comment: @basic i am using ms excel2010 that supports the around 10,48,576 rows as per information.. The basic problem is when once the sheet is created and rows are appended to sheet in a batch ..how to append the next batch of rows to that sheet...as u know openxml requires a particular format..if u want the format of xml which i am passing to excel wil provide to u...

Comment: Quite right re:2010. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to your Q

Comment: @lc. here i can put only some 600 chars only but the exception is having 2723 chars ..is there any way i can send to you the exception.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possibility that we can write data to exce in chunk
>   instead of writing in one shot.

No, but you can use the OpenXML libraries in conjunction with XmlTextWriter to get around issues like this.

Have a look at the source code in my free C# "Export to Excel" library which does this.

http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

I had the same issue when trying to build up "an image" of the entire Excel .xlsx file which I wanted to write *in memory*.   Eventually, your application will just run out of memory, and crash.

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is long, you can use

```
public override int GetBytes(
string s,
int charIndex,
int charCount,
byte[] bytes,
int byteIndex
)
```

to convert piece by piece, even reusing the byte array.